# How to find number of operations required to get Kaprekar constant?

Tags: algorithm, number-theory

Problem statement:

> Harry got a letter from Hogwarts School to join the wizardry. This letter consists of a magical key (6174) and a 4-digit number n with at least two distinct digits. Harry has to count in how many steps this number n can be converted to magical key invented by professor Dumbledore with this procedure as follows:

```
For example:
N = 1234
Step 1: x = 4321 y= 1234 => n = x-y => 3087
Step 2: x = 8730 y= 0378 => n = x-y => 8352
Step 3: x = 8532 y= 2358 => n = x-y => 6174 
and you are done.

Answer is 3
```

I am interested in knowing the minimum number of the above operations required to get `6174`

My solution which is kind of bfs gives TLE.

```py
a = input()
ref = a
b = 0
while(ref != "6174"):
    b=b+1
    ref=list(ref)
    num1="".join(sorted(ref))
    num2="".join(sorted(ref, reverse = True))
    num1=int(num1)
    num2=int(num2)
    diff=num2-num1
    ref=str(diff)
print(b)
```

Is it possible to reduce time complexity?

Comment: why would you use bfs? I don't see any tree here. Each step leads to one and only one outcome. Some caching would help to find whether there is a cycle that prevents a solution completely.

Comment: Also, please post your current solution so people can take a closer look at it.

Comment: @user1984 done, now can you improve time?

Comment: I don't think there is a guarantee that there is **any** solution at all. So, you may be stuck in a cycle. To avoid that, keep track of the seen numbers in form of a `set` and check if you have already considered a specific number before working on it. If you have already seen it, it means that there is no solution.

Comment: @user1984 it was given that at least two digits will be different so we will never end up in loop and we will get `6174` for sure.

Comment: Can you please provide the input for which your algorithm TLEs?